# Issue in reading stored procedure parameter value

Tags: c#, wcf, stored-procedures

I am unable to read value from stored procedure when executing it.

Here is my stored procedure

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[SaveInvitation]
(
    @InvitationID INT OUTPUT,
    @UserID INT,
    @Email NCHAR(100),
    @InvitationGUID  UNIQUEIDENTIFIER OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRY
    IF @UserID = -1
        BEGIN
            SET @UserID = NULL
        END

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Invitations WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(Email)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(@Email)))
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO Invitations (UserID,
                    Email,
                    CreateDate)
            VALUES (@UserID,
                    @Email,
                    GETDATE())

            -- GET NEWLY INSERTED INVITATIONS ID
            SET @InvitationID = IDENT_CURRENT('Invitations')

            -- GET GUID FROM INVITATION ID
            SELECT  @InvitationGUID = InvitationGUID
            FROM    Invitations
            WHERE   InvitationID = @InvitationID
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR('ALREADY_INVITATED', 16, 127)
        END
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK
        END
    EXEC ThrowError
END CATCH
END
```

I am executing this procedure from this function

My `DataBaseModel.Designer.cs`:

```
public ObjectResult<SaveInvitation_Result> SaveInvitation(ObjectParameter invitationID, Nullable<global::System.Int32> userID, global::System.String email, ObjectParameter invitationGUID)
    {
        ObjectParameter userIDParameter;
        if (userID.HasValue)
        {
            userIDParameter = new ObjectParameter("UserID", userID);
        }
        else
        {
            userIDParameter = new ObjectParameter("UserID", typeof(global::System.Int32));
        }

        ObjectParameter emailParameter;
        if (email != null)
        {
            emailParameter = new ObjectParameter("Email", email);
        }
        else
        {
            emailParameter = new ObjectParameter("Email", typeof(global::System.String));
        }

        return base.ExecuteFunction<SaveInvitation_Result>("SaveInvitation", invitationID, userIDParameter, emailParameter, invitationGUID);
    }
```

It throws an exception

> *The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'TestModel.SaveInvitation_Result'. A member of the type, 'InvitationGUID', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.*

I have created a complex type i.e. `SaveUserRegistration_Result` and imported one function `SaveInvitation` of return type  `SaveUserRegistration_Result`.

How can I solve above exception? Is there any change in stored procedure?

Screen shot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's giving you this error because you're not actually `SELECT`ing back a result. If you added a line ***to the end of*** your procedure for example:

```
SELECT  @InvitationGUID AS InvitationGUID
```

It should work just fine for you.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Is it neccessary to give like this? I get this error The parameter at index 0 in the parameters array is null.

Comment: In DataBaseModel.Designer.cs I doesn't pass nay value to invitationID,invitationGUID

Comment: Oh I see, you will need to remove those parameters (they are currently `OUTPUT` parameters) and you will want to then `SELECT` both of them back if you need them both in the `SaveInvitation_Result`. In short, don't use `OUTPUT` parameters but rather issue a `SELECT` statement that returns a row that has matching column names for matching property names in `SaveInvitation_Result`.

Comment: It is a auto generated funcation so parameter comes in this funcation is also auto generate. If I remove manually and update my service then parameter automatically comes in funcation. I have added screen shot of my funcation.